# Selenium Python - How and if to use IF/ELSE in Date-picker?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am new to Python/Selenium. I am trying to create a statement where if the element is not found the code should do something else. Here is the line of code.

```
pickActiveDay = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="datepicker-days"]//table[@class="table-condensed"]//td[@class="day"]')
nextMonth = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//th[@class="next"]')

    if pickActiveDay.is_displayed():
        pickActiveDay.click()
    else:
        nextMonth.click()
```

I intentionally closed dates and made pickActiveDay not clickable.

I get this error: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //div[@class="datepicker-days"]//table[@class="table-condensed"]//td[@class="day"]

Shouldn't the code move to else statement?

Can you please help out?

Answer (score 0):

the error is on the find_element_by_xpath('here is the error'), you can change it for this.

```
pickActiveDay = driver.find_element_by_id('name of id')
nextMonth = driver.find_element_by_id('name of id')

if pickActiveDay.is_displayed():
    pickActiveDay.click()
else:
    nextMonth.click()
```

try to change the xpath to id, name, class_name, etc

Comment: I don't have id, name, class_name for those elements. That is why I created xpath

Comment: okey, in that case your xpath is wrong, when you define xpath it has to go like this: Xpath=//tagname[@attribute='value']